# Codeigniter - Attach a file from CDN

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, cdn

I am trying to attach a file from from my website using pulling from my CDN using CodeIgniter.  It does not attach I am assuming because cross domain security issue.  How can I attach a file using CodeIgniter from another server that I have control over?

```
$this->load->helper('email');

$this->email->from('services@domain-name.com');
$this->email->to($this->input->post('email')); 

$retval = $this->crud_model->read('posts', $post_id);
$post = $retval[0];

$this->email->subject($post->title);
$this->email->message('Location: '.$this->config->item('cdn_media_url').$post->image_path);
$this->email->attach($this->config->item('cdn_media_url').$post->image_path);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach HTTP Location headers and URLs to e-mail. That just doesn't make sense.

Download the image from your CDN with `file_get_contents` or `cURL`, then you can provide its local path on your server in the code.